# How to descturcture an object in Typescript when properties are optional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a generic component which has some optional properties, I need to destructure props but I get errors

```
    interface IScenarioPageProps extends IScenarioStateWithDispatch {
    isOverlayVisible?: boolean;
    renderOverlayContent?: () => void;
}

const Page = (props: IStepStateWithDispatch | IScenarioPageProps | ITaskStateWithDispatch) => {
    const { taskState, stepState, isOverlayVisible, renderOverlayContent } = props;
    const { selectedTaskId, selectedTask } = taskState;
    const { selectedStepId, selectedStep } = stepState;

    const style = StyleSheet.create({
        content: {
            'background-color': getTheme().palette.white,
            height: '100vh'
        }
    });

    return (
        <div className={css(style.content)}>
            {isOverlayVisible && <Modal>{renderOverlayContent()}</Modal>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Page;
```

How can I destructure those optional properties without getting Typescript error?

[image]

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: updated with error image

Comment: You first need to better type `props`, its current type `IStepStateWithDispatch | IScenarioPageProps | ITaskStateWithDispatch` consists of intersections of those types, hence you don't have that field.

Comment: Please add the `IStepStateWithDispatch`, `ITaskStateWithDispatch` and `IScenarioStateWithDispatch` types declaration

Comment: only IScenarioPageProps  has those props that Typescript is complaining

Comment: It's clear from the question. I mean add the declarations to the code in the question.

Comment: It's very long - and doesn't add any value

Comment: @NeginBasiri `renderOverlayContent()` should be in the other interfaces, or props should be defined to include `{ renderOverlayContent?: () => void }` - if this can't be done, you'll have to abandon type safety in `Page` and do run-time checking for `renderOverlayContent()`

Comment: @DacreDenny Thanks - how to abandon type safety in Page and do run-time checking for renderOverlayContent()?

Comment: In order to answer this I need the declarations of the other types

Comment: You can destructure straight from your props object since it is guaranteed to be defined, but any of those values can be undefined if not required, so you should instead use the guard pattern to access those properties.

Comment: @DrewReese whats the guard pattern?

Comment: `taskState && taskState.selectedTaskId` this first tests that `taskState` is truthy and if so continues evaluating. If `taskState` is undefined, the condition is falsy and the rest of the expression is ignored.  This pattern sometimes also sometimes called a guard clause.

Comment: @DrewReese  I added 
let isOverlayVisible = props.isOverlayVisible ? props.isOverlayVisible : null;

Comment: Yeah, this does not appear to be a destructuring issue, but rather a proptype validation issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Page` component uses the `renderOverlayContent` prop regardless and the prop isn't presented in the `IStepStateWithDispatch` or `ITaskStateWithDispatch` type (that's the reason of the error), I can make a assumption that you want the `Page` component to require **all** the props of the interfaces `IStepStateWithDispatch`, `IScenarioPageProps` and `ITaskStateWithDispatch`.

If my assumption is correct, then you need to replace `|` with `&` in the props type declaration. It will tell TypeScript that the `props` object has the properties from all the interfaces.

```js
const Page = (props: IStepStateWithDispatch & IScenarioPageProps & ITaskStateWithDispatch) => {
    // ...
}
```

If my assumption is not correct (the component is polymorphic), then you need to check that the `renderOverlayContent` prop is given and then use it:

```js
// ...

// const {renderOverlayContent} = props; // Remove this

return (
    <div className={css(style.content)}>
        {isOverlayVisible &&
            <Modal>
                {'renderOverlayContent' in props && props.renderOverlayContent && props.renderOverlayContent()}
            </Modal>
        }
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks ... 'renderOverlayContent' in props && props.renderOverlayContent solved my problem